# How to push a new code to an existing git repository in github

Tags: windows, git, github, git-bash, git-push

I need to push my modified new java code to my old git repository in github but I do not have old code in my pc. How to do that?

I had push a code before my github account before. Now I don't have that old code in my pc. How do I pull the project into my pc and after making changes, push again  to the same repository?

I do not have much experience in github, so please help me to improve skills on github.

Comment: Can you provide more information, such as your operating system and the process you used to download the git repository?

Comment: my operating system is **Windows** and I have a repository in github that I have created before.now I have developed my old code and I need to Push this code to that old repository. @GreenCloakGuy

Comment: You should add your old repository as a new origin, e.g.
`git remote add old-repo <old-repo-url>`
Then you can push the code like this:
`git push old-repo <branch-name>`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check your remote first to see where it is pointing to by

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@<old-git-url>/<project>.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@g<old-git-url>/<project>.git (push)
```

Change the pointing to GitHub

```
$ git remote set-url origin ssh://git@<github-url>/<project>.git
```

Now your repo is pointing to Github

Now you can make your changes and then add them and do a commit and finally push to remote branch; say you are on master.

```
git add <file>
git commit -m <commit message>
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 4):

I had to do just that and achieved it like this.

**Setup.** I assume you have a new remote repository with files that may not cause a conflict with the directory you currently have locally.

1. Git clone from the git repository you need to push to. Just make sure you create a new directory for the cloned code.
2. Copy the contents of the cloned repository into the local directory that has your current code. Make sure to copy the .git (hidden) file.
3. cd into your local directory and run `git remote -v`. You should see the remote repository git address.
4. `git add -A` to add whatever change you require and commit it.
5. Finally git push

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<USER>/<repo>.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: This will not add to the existing history, instead you're just trying to push an unrelated main to the old repo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your local repository (the one that is on your computer) is connected to the remote repository (the one that is on the GitHub servers).

After this, you need to add the modified file to the *staging area*. Say, you have a file *test.txt* that you have modified, you would add it to the staging area by typing

```
git add test.txt
```

After that you would need to commit those changes. You can do that by

```
git commit -m "commit message"
```

And that's it, you have now saved those changes and recorded them in the version control. But the changes that you made have only been recorded in your local repository and you would need to *push* these changes to the remote repository (the GitHub servers). You can do this by

```
git push origin master
```

It would take a few seconds (depending on your internet speed and the project file size) to push these changes to the remote servers. Once it's done, you can open that repository on GitHub and see the changes for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to download Git Desktop to skip running commands.

1. Clone Repository [image]
2. Select Git repository to clone and choose local path. See picture
   [image]

DONE you have your git repo project in your local computer. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Just to amend the top answer by Pankaj Saini,

Check your remote first to see where it is pointing to by

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@<old-git-url>/<project>.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@g<old-git-url>/<project>.git (push)
```

Change the pointing to GitHub

$ git remote set-url origin ssh://git@/.git
Now your repo is pointing to Github

Now you can make your changes and then add them and do a commit and finally push to remote branch; say you are on master.

```
git add <file>
git commit -m <commit message>
git push origin master
```

I believe "master" is now "main" in some instances or platforms. If this answer isn't working for you, try swapping that out. It worked for me.
like so....

```js
git push origin main
```

Comment: This could've been a comment to the question.